# Can't understand binary search function

Tags: c++, binary-search

Help me understand the usage of Binary search in this problem: 
[Problem](https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=1901&rd=4650)

> Write a class FairWorkload with a method getMostWork which takes a int[] folders (the number of folders for each filing cabinet) and an int workers (the number of workers). The method should return an int which is the maximum amount of folders that a worker would have to look through in an optimal partitioning of the filing cabinets.

The code is

```
int getMostWork( vector  folders, int workers ) {
    int n = folders.size();
    int lo = *max_element( folders.begin(), folders.end() );
    int hi = accumulate( folders.begin(), folders.end(), 0 );

    while ( lo < hi ) {
      int x = lo + (hi-lo)/2;

      int required = 1, current_load = 0;
      for ( int i=0; i<n; ++i ) {
         if ( current_load + folders[i] <= x ) {
            // the current worker can handle it
            current_load += folders[i];
         }
         else {
            // assign next worker
            ++required;
            current_load = folders[i];               
         }
      }

      if ( required <= workers )
         hi = x;
      else
         lo = x+1;
    }

    return lo;
}
```

I don't get the part:

```
 if ( required <= workers )
    hi = x;
 else
    lo = x+1;
```

Can someone explain me this code and this part, please?

Comment: Yes, it's an if/else statement with 2 assignments.

Comment: That was helpful

Comment: You should understand binary searches before trying to understand the code.

Comment: What part or section of the code are you having issues with?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Can you tell me why binary search for this problem works? Like how can I read the problem statement and know that binary search will work for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here binary search is being used to find the optimal solution.For binary search you need a range represented by `high` and `low`.You know the optimal answer lies within this range.In this particular problem `low` is represented by the minimum number of folders that a worker will have to look for, which is going to be the maximum number of folders in a cabinet

```
int lo = *max_element( folders.begin(), folders.end() );
```

The `high` would be if only one worker is assigned all folders which would be sum of all values in `folders`

```
int hi = accumulate( folders.begin(), folders.end(), 0 );
```

Now you loop through this range and try to find the optimal answer.

```
 while ( lo < hi ) {
      int x = lo + (hi-lo)/2;
```

In each iteration of the loop you check the number of workers required if each worker was given maximum `x` folders.
You then decide the next range by checking if you were able to satisfy the constraint with `x` as solution and try to get more optimal solution

```
if ( required <= workers )
     hi = x;
```

If `x` is the solution, then i need `required` workers which is less than or equal to the `workers`, so i will try to get more optimal by having a lower value of maximum number of folders assigned to a worker.To do this you change the range to `[lo,x]`

```
 else
lo = x+1;
```

On the contrary if you need more workers than present, you will increase the range to `[x+1,hi]`

Answer (score 0):

First extract the middle function:

```
int CountRequiredWorkers(const std::vector<int>& folders, int load) {
    int required = 1, current_load = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (current_load + folders[i] <= x) {
            // the current worker can handle it
            current_load += folders[i];
        } else {
            // assign next worker
            ++required;
            current_load = folders[i];               
        }
    }
    return required;
}

int getMostWork(const vector<int>& folders, int workers) {
    int n = folders.size();
    int lo = *max_element( folders.begin(), folders.end() );
    int hi = accumulate( folders.begin(), folders.end(), 0 );

    while ( lo < hi ) {
      const int mid = lo + (hi-lo)/2;
      const int required = CountRequiredWorkers(mid);

      if (required <= workers)
         hi = mid;
      else
         lo = mid + 1;
    }
    return lo;
}
```

So we do binary search of a "virtual" array where index is total work, and value is worker count. valid indexes are from the biggest folder to the total of all folders.
That array look like `{N, N - 1, N - 1, ..., 2, 2, 1}`, and we want first index `< workers`.